# Angular CLI - changing where my components get generated

Tags: angular-cli

**Is there anyway to change the default location of my generated components in angular cli config?**

I want to change where my angular CLI defaults its generated components to a specific components folder.  After upgrading to angular 9 I get the following error when trying to generate a component outside of the root folder, which I never used to get:

```
Could not find an NgModule. Use the skip-import option to skip importing in NgModule.
```

I can only seem to generate components and services from the root/src folder and nowhere else.

Just upgraded my angular and angular cli.  Currently running:

```
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.2
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.2
@angular/cli                      9.0.2
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.2
@schematics/angular               9.0.2
@schematics/update                0.900.2
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to generate the component as follow:

```
ng g c componentName [folder] --skip-import
```

e.g:

```
ng g c myComponent myComponentFolder --skip-import
```

and then add the component in the declarations array of your `app.module.ts` file manually.

Comment: got it however - with angular 6 which I was using until last week I could generate a component from any directory and now I have to be in root/src and nowhere else.  Is this the --skip-import step?

Comment: I am not sure why but in Angular 9 you must use --skip-import if you want create a new component. In other way it gives you the same error every time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes like this =>
ng generate component folder/nameComponent